# I/O Error while saving Excel file - Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Im using python to open an existing excel file and do some formatting and save and close the file. My code is working good when the file size is small but when excel size is big (apprx. 40MB) I'm getting  Serialization I/O error and Im sure it due to memory problem or due to my code. Kindly help.

System Config:

RAM - 8 GB
32 - bit operation 
Windows 7

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import colors, Font


dest_loc='/Users/abdulr06/Documents/Python Scripts/'

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

SRC='TSYS'
YM1='201707'

dest_file=dest_loc+SRC+'_'+''+YM1+'.xlsx'  

sheetname = [SRC+''+' GL-Recon']   


#Following code is common for rest of the sourc systems 
wb=load_workbook(dest_file)

fmtB=Font(color=colors.BLUE) 
fmtR=Font(color=colors.RED)

for i in range(len(sheetname)):             

  sheet1=wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname[i])             
  print(sheetname[i])  

  last_record=sheet1.max_row+1 

  for m in range(2,last_record):
      if -30 <= sheet1.cell(row=m,column=5).value <=30:          
          ft=sheet1.cell(row=m,column=5)
          ft.font=fmtB
          ft.number_format = '_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)'
          ft1=sheet1.cell(row=m,column=6)
          ft1.number_format = '0.00%'
      else:          
          ft=sheet1.cell(row=m,column=5)  
          ft.font=fmtR  
          ft.number_format = '_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)'
          ft1=sheet1.cell(row=m,column=6)
          ft1.number_format = '0.00%' 
wb.save(filename=dest_file)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-fc16d9a46046>", line 6, in <module>
    wb.save(filename=dest_file)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 263, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 239, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 222, in save
    self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 80, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 163, in _write_worksheets
    xml = sheet._write(self.workbook.shared_strings)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 776, in _write
    return write_worksheet(self, shared_strings)

  File "C:\Users\abdulr06\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 263, in write_worksheet
    xf.write(worksheet.page_breaks.to_tree())

  File "serializer.pxi", line 1016, in lxml.etree._FileWriterElement.__exit__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:141944)

  File "serializer.pxi", line 904, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter._write_end_element (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:140137)

  File "serializer.pxi", line 999, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter._handle_error (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:141630)

  File "serializer.pxi", line 195, in lxml.etree._raiseSerialisationError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:131006)

SerialisationError: IO_WRITE
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace please?

Comment: I have added, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you allocate font at each loop?

```
fmt=Font(color=colors.BLUE)
```

Or red, create two fonts red and blue, once and then use it, each time you are allocating Font, you are using more memory.

Optimise your code at first. Less code `->` less errors, for example:

```
mycell = sheet1.cell(row=m,column=5)       
if -30 <= mycell.value <=30: 
    mycell.font = redfont
```

This should ensure that you do not have the issue again (hopefully)

Comment: I have tried but no luck the sheet which I'm accessing hardly contains any data.(4 columns & 35 rows.)

Comment: can you post the optimised version ?

Comment: Optimized version have been posted. Yes what you said is make sense. Less Code -> less errors.

Comment: 1/ can you try to load it and save it immediately without modifying => have you got error or not ?
2/ if you don't have errors on the first step, then I think you may have problem with number_format. so comment the whole program and try uncommenting each line to find which one produces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will debug and share my findings.