# Python, Pandas write to dataframe, lxml.etree.SerialisationError: IO_WRITE

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Code to pick the wanted lines from a dataframe. The original data is in Excel format and I put it in dataframe here.

I want to pick all the rows of “Test Date” fall in “201506” and “201508”, and write them to an Excel file. The lines are working fine.

```
import pandas as pd

data_short = {'Contract_type' : ["Other", "Other", "Type-I", "Type-I", "Type-I", "Type-II", "Type-II", "Type-III", "Type-III", "Part-time"],
'Test Date': ["20150816", "20150601", "20150204", "20150609", "20150204", "20150806", "20150201", "20150615", "20150822", "20150236" ],
'Test_time' : ["16:26", "07:39", "18:48", "22:32", "03:54", "03:30", "04:00", "22:02", "13:43", "10:29"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_short)

data_201508 = df[df['Test Date'].astype(str).str.startswith('201508')]
data_201506 = df[df['Test Date'].astype(str).str.startswith('201506')]

data_68 = data_201506.append(data_201508)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\test-output.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl')
data_68.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", index = False)
writer.save()
```

But when I applied them to a larger file, ~600,000 rows with 25 columns (65 MB in file size), it returns error message like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Working Scripts\LL move pick wanted ATA in months.py", line 15, in <module>
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 732, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 263, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 239, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 222, in save
    self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 80, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 163, in _write_worksheets
    xml = sheet._write(self.workbook.shared_strings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 776, in _write
    return write_worksheet(self, shared_strings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line 263, in write_worksheet
    xf.write(worksheet.page_breaks.to_tree())
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 1016, in lxml.etree._FileWriterElement.__exit__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:142025)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 904, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter._write_end_element (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:140218)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 999, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter._handle_error (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:141711)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 195, in lxml.etree._raiseSerialisationError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:131087)
lxml.etree.SerialisationError: IO_WRITE
```

Does it mean the computer is not good enough (8GB, Win10)? Is there a way to optimize the code (for example, consume less memory)? Thank you.

btw: Question similiar to [I/O Error while saving Excel file - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598571/i-o-error-while-saving-excel-file-python) but no solution...

Comment: did you try the `to_excel` function instead of the ExcelWriter?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: @MrE, thank you for the comment. I think that's what the code exactly does..

Answer (score 0):

found a solution: write the output to csv instead (anyway it can be opened in Excel as well)

```
data_wanted_all.to_csv("C:\\test-output.csv", index=False)
```

post here for in case some one encounters the same problem. let me know if this question shall be removed. :)